# How to split a string at commas but ignore \,?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to split string `http://some.com/\,brabra,400,500` into `['http://some.com/\,brabra', 400, 500]`

I already tried this, but error because lookbehind is not support in js. 

`'http://some.com/\,brabra,400,500'.split(/(?<!\\),/g)`

Any other ideas to do this?

Comment: Try [`split(/,(?=\d)/)`](https://regex101.com/r/tG5vE6/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use matching approach with `(?:[^,\\]+|\\.)+`:

```
match(/(?:[^,\\]+|\\.)+/g)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iP9cM5/1)

**Details**: the `(?:[^,\\]+|\\.)+` matches 1 or more occurrences (`(?:...)+`) of a 1+ characters other than `,` and `\` (with `[^,\\]+`) or (`|`) any escaped sequence (`\\.`)

```js
var s = "http://some.com/\\,brabra,400,500"
console.log(s.match(/(?:[^,\\]+|\\.)+/g));
```

Or a workaround if the comma to be split with is always followed with a digit:

```
split(/,(?=\d)/)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tG5vE6/1)

```js
var s = "http://some.com/\\,brabra,400,500"
console.log(s.split(/,(?=\d)/));
```

Comment: Nice. Could simplify slightly as `/(\\.|[^,])+/g`.

Comment: Awesome.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

you can use simulate positive lookaheads with reversing the string:

```js
String.prototype.reverse = function() {
  return this.split("").reverse().join("");
}

Array.prototype.reverseElements = function() {
  var ar = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (typeof this[i] === 'string')
      ar[i] = this[i].reverse();
    else {
      //Do something if not a String
    }
  }
  return ar;
}

var str = "http://some.com/\,brabra,400,500";
var ar = str.reverse().split(/,(?!\\)/).reverse().reverseElements();

console.log(ar);
```

**Note:** The Regex works [here](https://regex101.com/r/aV2bY4/1), but not in the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

A classic, if slightly inelegant approach for such problems is to replace some characters with a magic token, then put them back later:

```
str
  .replace("\\,", "DONT_SPLIT_HERE")
  .split(',')
  .map(part => part.replace("DONT_SPLIT_HERE", "\\,")
```